# Element props in jsx

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When describing certain element in render() I can define some props manually. For example

```
<ListItemText
    primary="Single-line item"
    secondary="Secondary text"
    className={classes.listItem}
    primaryTypographyProps={{ textOverflow: 'ellipsis', overflow: 'hidden', display:"inline" }}
    secondaryTypographyProps={{ textOverflow: 'ellipsis', overflow: 'hidden', display:"inline" }}
/>
```

I can define some properties in JSX within **`makeStyles`**. Like this:

```
listItem: {
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    textOverflow: 'ellipsis'
}
```

But how to define all props of abovementioned `**ListItemText**`?

Something like this gives me errors. I cant put object inside object.

```
listItem: {
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    primaryTypographyProps={{ textOverflow: 'ellipsis', overflow: 'hidden', display:"inline" }}
}
```

and this is not working at all. (not in `className` nor in `styles`)

```
listItem: {
    primary:"Single-line item"
},
```

My questions are
1. how to send these properties in jsx?
2. how to put object inside object in jsx?

Comment: What you are referring to as JSX is [JSS](https://cssinjs.org/?v=v10.1.1). It is not specifying element properties, it is specifying CSS. You can't control element properties via the CSS specified in `makeStyles`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. How to send these properties in jsx?**

Not sure what really this means. But if you just wanted to create an object and pass it as props then you can use destructuring.

```
const listItemProps = {
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    primaryTypographyProps: { textOverflow: 'ellipsis', overflow: 'hidden', display:"inline" }
};

<ListItemText {...listItemProps} />
```

If not this, you need to clarify more on `how to send these properties in JSX` statement.

**2. How to put object inside object in jsx?**

It doesn't make any sense. JavaScript objects are comprised of `key-value` pairs. No matter you write it in JSX or any other way.

`{{ textOverflow: 'ellipsis', overflow: 'hidden', display:"inline" }}` is not object inside object. It is just syntax in JSS to pass object as props for something like class/style attribute.

This is actually just an object actually. In react, expressions are written in `{}` when passing attributes other than text. This JSS syntax makes it possible for user to do that. Same concept is used in below as well.

```
<ListItemText max={1} checkByDefault={true} />
```

Above is also JSS syntax. Above `1` and `true` are passed as props. In your example you passed object as props. It was not object inside object.

Hope it helps.